# Having trouble selecting maximum id from table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table named 'users' with the the following columns:

```
ID
username
password
```

and I am creating a php script to grab the maximum ID from the table.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM users") or die("Error type 1");
$query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die("Error type 2");
$maxID = ($query_row[ID]) or die("Error type 3");
echo "$maxID";
?>
```

When I execute this php script, it prints "Error type 3". Does anyone know why?

Comment: The row that starts `$maxID = . . . ` doesn't look right.

Comment: Column is not called ID, but something like MAX(ID), try changing `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM users` to `SELECT MAX(ID) maxId FROM users` and then `$query_row[ID]` to `$query_row[MAXID]`, also consider using quotes.
Next thing is that you aren't checking whether you actually got something returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM users") or die("Error type 1");
$query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die("Error type 2");
$maxID = ($query_row["ID"]) or die("Error type 3");
echo "$maxID";
?>
```

It gives `MAX(ID)` an alias of `ID` and then you should write `ID` between quotes

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two points to improve:

1) It's recommended to create an alias to your column

2) The returned value can the evaluate as `false` by PHP, so take care

I suggest you to use:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT MAX(ID) as max_id FROM users') or die('Error type 1');
$query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die('Error type 2');
$maxID = ! empty($query_row[max_id]) or die('Error type 3');
```